# Postfix Relay to Mandrill: Sends some email, others queued but disappears

Tags: postfix-mta, mandrill

We set up Mandrill about 6 months ago to run thru postfix on the server and ensure all applications sending email relays to Mandrill.

It seems recently that we've been starting to hear from our clients that they aren't getting some emails that they have been expecting sent (like email notifications of store purchases, etc). I've experienced this happening as well, but seemingly randomly. It's not just ONE specific application, as we've seen the issue across Perl, PHP, Ruby. So it is something with Postfix.

We see the attempted queue of the "missing" emails in the maillogs, and have been able to see different looking status between ones we see that come thru vs. the ones that don't. However, we're not able to determine WHAT is happening to the email at that point.

I have confirmed in Mandrill's report interface, no record of the identified emails coming to it. So it's even being passed on to Mandrill either.

Here are mail logs of some specific transactions, all from the same application sending out a sales transaction email. The first one shows an email I did receive (as one of the recipients). And the other two are ones I still have yet to receive (along with other recipients):

Received Email:

```
Sep  4 14:52:29 serverABC sendmail[18143]: s84IqSaq018143: from=apache, size=10054, class=0, nrcpts=4, msgid=<201409041852.s84IqSaq018143@serverABC.mydomain.com>, relay=apache@localhost
Sep  4 14:52:29 serverABC postfix/smtpd[14952]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Sep  4 14:52:29 serverABC postfix/smtpd[14952]: 09AB632CE053: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Sep  4 14:52:29 serverABC postfix/cleanup[14959]: 09AB632CE053: message-id=<201409041852.s84IqSaq018143@serverABC.mydomain.com>
Sep  4 14:52:29 serverABC postfix/qmgr[1713]: 09AB632CE053: from=<apache@serverABC.mydomain.com>, size=10475, nrcpt=4 (queue active)
Sep  4 14:52:29 serverABC sendmail[18143]: s84IqSaq018143: to=Flmt@clientcompany.com,store@thestore.com,rich@mydomain.com,=?utf-8?B?S2FyZW4gQ29sYXZpdG8=?= <karen@redacted.com>, ctladdr=apache (48/48), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=130054, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (Ok: queued as 09AB632CE053)
Sep  4 14:52:29 serverABC postfix/smtpd[14952]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Sep  4 14:52:29 serverABC postfix/smtp[15569]: 09AB632CE053: to=<rich@mydomain.com>, relay=smtp.mandrillapp.com[54.205.6.2]:25, delay=0.49, delays=0.11/0/0.27/0.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 677011C0A00)
Sep  4 14:52:29 serverABC postfix/smtp[15569]: 09AB632CE053: to=<karen@redacted.com>, relay=smtp.mandrillapp.com[54.205.6.2]:25, delay=0.49, delays=0.11/0/0.27/0.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 677011C0A00)
Sep  4 14:52:29 serverABC postfix/smtp[15569]: 09AB632CE053: to=<store@thestore.com>, relay=smtp.mandrillapp.com[54.205.6.2]:25, delay=0.49, delays=0.11/0/0.27/0.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 677011C0A00)
Sep  4 14:52:29 serverABC postfix/smtp[15569]: 09AB632CE053: to=<Flmt@clientcompany.com>, relay=smtp.mandrillapp.com[54.205.6.2]:25, delay=0.49, delays=0.11/0/0.27/0.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 677011C0A00)
Sep  4 14:52:29 serverABC postfix/qmgr[1713]: 09AB632CE053: removed
```

---

Email not received, same type of transaction:

```
Sep  4 15:01:05 serverABC sendmail[24776]: s84J13UJ024776: from=apache, size=10308, class=0, nrcpts=4, msgid=<201409041901.s84J13UJ024776@serverABC.mydomain.com>, relay=apache@localhost
Sep  4 15:01:05 serverABC sendmail[24776]: s84J13UJ024776: to==?utf-8?B?VGFuYSBDbGFyaw==?= <clarktana@poppermail.com>, delay=00:00:02, mailer=relay, pri=130308, stat=queued
Sep  4 15:01:05 serverABC sendmail[24776]: s84J13UJ024776: to=rich@mydomain.com, delay=00:00:02, mailer=relay, pri=130308, stat=queued
Sep  4 15:01:05 serverABC sendmail[24776]: s84J13UJ024776: to=store@thestore.com, delay=00:00:02, mailer=relay, pri=130308, stat=queued
Sep  4 15:01:05 serverABC sendmail[24776]: s84J13UJ024776: to=Flmt@clientcompany.com, delay=00:00:02, mailer=relay, pri=130308, stat=queued
```

---

Another One Not Received:

```
Sep  4 15:23:25 serverABC sendmail[9756]: s84JNM7c009756: from=apache, size=10289, class=0, nrcpts=4, msgid=<201409041923.s84JNM7c009756@serverABC.mydomain.com>, relay=apache@localhost
Sep  4 15:23:25 serverABC sendmail[9756]: s84JNM7c009756: to==?utf-8?B?R2FyeSBHcmF2ZXM=?= <joesdjj@sod.com>, delay=00:00:03, mailer=relay, pri=130289, stat=queued
Sep  4 15:23:25 serverABC sendmail[9756]: s84JNM7c009756: to=rich@mydomain.com, delay=00:00:03, mailer=relay, pri=130289, stat=queued
Sep  4 15:23:25 serverABC sendmail[9756]: s84JNM7c009756: to=store@thestore.com, delay=00:00:03, mailer=relay, pri=130289, stat=queued
Sep  4 15:23:25 serverABC sendmail[9756]: s84JNM7c009756: to=Flmt@clientcompany.com, delay=00:00:03, mailer=relay, pri=130289, stat=queued
```

---

You can see the obvious difference in the two sets of logs. One shows the relay to smtp.mandrill.com. The other shows queued, but never makes it to mandrill, or anywhere else.

Mailq is always showing empty, so not getting stuck, unless there's another queue I can't see (deferred, maildrop, hold, etc)?